# Question about Back Office features

Tags: cognito-forms

Do you all perform the following features?

1. Ability to provide a comprehensive standard summary report
2. Ability to enhance filtering data
3. Ability to download to Excel and .pdf
4. Ability to create fields that are not shown on the public form

New features

1. Ability to provide a customizable report by extracting various fields
2. Ability to import Excel data
3. Ability to have multiple user controlled edits

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

1. Yes, by exporting to Excel you have the ability to create summary reports. Within Cognito this is not currently a feature however we at looking to add a feature similar to this and progress can be followed over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Ah36la77).
2. Yes, by exporting to Excel you can filter the data. Within Cognito this is not currently a feature however we are looking to add a feature in the same feature as the previous option, progress can be tracked via the same Idea board link.
3. Yes, Cognito Forms entries can be exported to Excel and with the use of Zapier entries can also be exported to pdf.
4. Yes, We do offer the ability have fields that are for internal use only. Any field can be set to this by using the fields "Show This Field" setting to either "Internally", which will show the field in all admin areas e.g. Preview, Publish, Entries, and "Never" which will only show the field in the Entries area.

As for your New Features.

1. This is a feature we do hope to release in the future, you can find this on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/nH7mk894).
2. We are also planning to add this feature in the future as well, You can find this on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/i2tOtG9u).
3. We are in the process of testing our multiple user controls currently and plan to release this feature in April. You can find this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/FDjI6zak).